# How to a invoke google search on a subview with a search string passed from Main view on an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

My application has two views and I want to invoke a google search on Second view with a search string (it is name of a product. For example 'Samsung Mobile') passed from application's Main view.

I dont want to enter product name in Google search field manually. It should be done automatically when I press the button on the Main View and the result page should be displayed on Sub View.

```
-(void) setLabelText:(NSString *) myNewText
{
    [productName setText:myNewText];

    NSURL *theURL =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];

    [webSearchView loadRequest:theRequest];
}
```

Just wondering is it possible to pass the search string as a parameter with the above function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com?q=%@", searchString];
NSURL *theURL =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Don't forget to escape `urlString` before passing it to NSURL if it contains spaces, special characters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works fine for single word string. Even though I have some product names contains two words separated by 'space' or '('. For example 'Samsung Mobile' or 'Nokia (N90). I hope these special characters should be replaced with '+' before passing it to URL string.

Comment: @Sibin that's why I wrote the last sentence :) Have a look at `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`.

Comment: Instead of CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes() I am suing the code given below to replace special characters,                     NSMutableString *strNew = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myNewText];
     
[strNew setString: [strNew stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];
Here I am not able to replace < " > character with < + > like the previous line of code. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sibin **Have a look at `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`**. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

As per H2CO3's answer, but I think the Google search URL may have changed. I also prefer https over http:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://google.com/search?q=%@", searchString];
NSURL *theURL =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```